# Wix: Public secure property is not updated from gui on InstallExecuteSequence

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer, properties

i'm not too much exp in wix, so maybe my question is silly, but i could not find the answer to it.
I define secure, public property:

```
<Property Id="REPORTSERVERNAME" Secure="yes"/>
```

then later in the code i have CA's:

```
<CustomAction Id="Create_Folder_MyReports_Cmd" Property="Create_Folder_MyReports" Value="&quot;rs.exe&quot; -i &quot;[DBINSTALLLOCATION]RSS Scripts\CreateFolder.rss&quot; -s http://[REPORTSERVERNAME]/Reportserver -v parentFolder=&quot;/&quot; -v folderName=&quot;MyReports&quot; -v folderHidden=&quot;FALSE&quot;" Execute="immediate" />
<CustomAction Id="Create_Folder_MyReports" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec" Execute="deferred" Return="check" Impersonate="yes"  />
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="Create_Folder_MyReports_Cmd" Before="Create_Folder_MyReports"></Custom>
  <Custom Action="Create_Folder_MyReports" Before="InstallFinalize" ></Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

and in dialog i have an edit:

```
<Control Id="ReportServer" Type="Edit" X="75" Y="72" Width="170" Height="18" Property="REPORTSERVERNAME"/>
```

so in log i have:
SecureCustomProperties = REPORTSERVERNAME
and value is changing well, but in the CA execution it's just empty. Can't realy figure out the problem.
Help plz, if you have any ideas.

Answer (score 2):

I see you have a deferred custom action. You have access only to some properties from deferred CAs.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370543(VS.85).aspx

You have to use CustomActionData to pass your property.